# Entity Framework 6 - Apply Custom SQL expression to select column for Sql to execute

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We are working on a solution using EF6/MSSQL where we can round Date/Times based on user query input (ie, 5 minute rounding, 10, etc)

Example query would be:

*(this is just mock-up and does not represent anything functional)*

```
from item in context.MyView 
select item.DataTimeStamp.RoundToNearest(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
```

Obviously, RoundToNearest(TimeSpan) does not exist, and is not Entity Framework Compatible.

I imagine I would implement an ExpressionVisitor with a VisitMethodCall, and apply my Expression when that method RoundToNearest was requested, but I cant seem to get that far.

We are dynamically building up the query, so we can use with aggregation (group by, etc).  The usage above is just for proof of concept.

If we wanted to add our own formula to a column using an extension method, that would translate to an SQL expression, how would we do that?

What I have so far (not working of course)

```
public static DateTime RoundToNearest(this DateTime date, TimeSpan period)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("This method should not be called directly. This will be called by an expression visitor");
    }


class DbFunctionsBinder : ExpressionVisitor
{
      protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
      {
           if (node.Object == null || node.Object.Type != typeof(DateTime)) return base.VisitMethodCall(node);

           switch (node.Method.Name)
           {
               case nameof(RoundToNearest):
                   return Expr((DateTime timeValue, TimeSpan roundValue) => timeValue.Date)  // Code Later 
                   .WithParameters(Visit(node.Object), Visit(node.Arguments[0]));
           }
           return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
       }
}
```

Once I get that, I will work to create the equivalent Expression from this SQL statement:

```
select top 10000
(
    CAST(
        -- Round with Truncate Round(value,0,1)
        ROUND(
            CAST(DataTimeStamp AS FLOAT) * (1440/5.0),0,1)/(1440/5.0) 
        as Datetime)
 ) as TheRoundedTime 
from DataSourceTable
```

Where the 5.0 value shown will be the decimal value for TotalMinutes on the TimeSpan passed into the extension method.

At the moment, I am at the error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in mscorlib.dll
>   LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime RoundToNearest(System.DateTime, System.TimeSpan)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Notes:

- We do not want to do this process in memory. We are processing millions of records in a single call and would like to keep this on the SQL server
- We have already implemented ExpressionVisitor for other functions like AddHours,AddMinutes,etc, which work great. We are looking now to extend that to return an expression.
- We are not interested in making this a Sql function unless we can map the Extension method to it as part of the Expression.
- If you have a better idea for rounding date/times without doing it in memory, open to ideas. Once completed, we will create a RoundDown, RoundNearest, RoundUp extension method. We just need one right now for the concept.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, since the method you are trying to replace is *static*, `node.Object` will be `null`.

Comment: I was hoping you would chime in Ivan!   Is what I am trying accomplish something that is achievable?

Comment: Hehe, it's been a quite time since we were fighting `AddHours` :) Seriously, if you can create EF compatible expression, why not. There is no problem to replace method call with something else - as soon as the result type is the same.